# laravel vagrant homestead doesnt create directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, homestead

i tryed everything but really can´t find the solution... I want to install homestead but when i do vagrant up or homestead up it just dont create directory or files. here is terminal
Can someone give help?
Thanks in advance!

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: homestead
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 => 8000 (adapter 1)
    default: 443 => 44300 (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 => 33060 (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 => 54320 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: 
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default: 
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if its present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/Perez/Homestead
    default: /home/vagrant/projects => /Users/Perez/Homestead/projects
==> default: Running provisioner: file...
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDXQVws5AGfpExLnJz5KMEqxwC2+hGvdNZL63Pi3HhGo+iOI7rqJhNpYn9KnsfK/kohfl6ByxzetgzBGA793aQOMPR8x/O5Ho+QsaftZnywvIqIOSwcWASWn2jYxxe/FKJ8Pk6tJEt0W3JxoHYbObOYQxj2PtEeBj+UvFjZF4i8u+ZO2DikOE9WLaVygLeZ43bcg0g+vlPoKangmvcekPWhqLQqysm/V94e8VscT1nKMgTO2GeC1CBUPWRZUMK5Afq6J2T98mgsp9NMMW7RvIK4Nvs5iUluuyW5rCh1TMyeCKsIq3uPOuiUEDd7sGiOK9ea++lGEJdTss2YN11m3b3d jacperestrelo@gmail.com
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default:  * Restarting nginx nginx
==> default:    ...done.
==> default: php5-fpm stop/waiting
==> default: php5-fpm start/running, process 2058
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/7q/nkxx6h8j759cplvbvs1x842w0000gp/T/vagrant-shell20141220-1085-1epuhti.sh
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
==> default: Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/7q/nkxx6h8j759cplvbvs1x842w0000gp/T/vagrant-shell20141220-1085-o5766a.sh
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: php5-fpm stop/waiting
==> default: php5-fpm start/running, process 2166
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: You are already using composer version a422d67e2701860a44a4634f62f88b58b8636468.
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/7q/nkxx6h8j759cplvbvs1x842w0000gp/T/vagrant-shell20141220-1085-1bnb42k.sh
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
```

Comment: What directories do you think it should be making? You should be linking to your actual directories...

Comment: (on linux) Config: is in `/home/{user}/.homestead/Homestead.yml`. Homestead itself is in `/home/{user}/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead`. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: I think he is asking why the actual code for laravel isn't where it should be. I am experiencing the same issue. The VM is running fine. I ssh in and there is no laravel code.